# How to use CIL instruction conv.r4

Tags: .net, cil

Today I started to learn how CIL code works.
I found [List of CIL instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)

And now I'm trying to edit one function.
I'm using .NET Reflector with Reflexil
I want to edit this function:

```
.method family hidebysig instance void SomeFunction(float32 var1, float32 var2, class SomeClassComponent component, class SomeInstanceClassComponent instance, float32 var3) cil managed
{
}
```

It's starting with code:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldarg.3
IL_0002: ldarg.1
IL_0003: ldarg.2
```

I want to replace var1 with hard-written value.
Wikipedia says:

```
conv.r4
```

**Convert to float32, pushing F on stack.**

When I try do edit it, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

Where's my mistake?

Comment: The evaluation stack is empty at the method start. You're trying to pop an empty stack with that opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucas Trzesniewski said in his comment, you first **need** to have **a value on the stack** which the conv.r4 instruction can use.

For a more in depth **description about the operands**, see this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes(v=vs.110).aspx) and here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_r4(v=vs.110).aspx) for the conv.r4 operand which states that "The conv.r4 opcode converts the value on top of the stack to the type specified in the opcode" - meaning you have to make sure that there is already a value on the stack and it is the correct value that the conv.r4 instruction can use.

As some minor self advertisement at the end ;) I've written some **tutorials about IL programming** you can read [here](https://dolinkamark.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/cil-programming-tutorial-the-basics/) and [here](https://dolinkamark.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/cil-programming-tutorial-the-basics-part-ii/). I tried to use a hands on approach so you understand IL through programming, not just reading.